ERROR - Error sending message to 6718717863: Message to be replied not found (aiogram)
I make my own echo bot that sends out a message to all bot users, kind of like an anonymous chat. (echo-to-all) I'm trying to add replies to it, and when i reply to my own message it's fine, but if i try to reply to someone else's message, i get an error: Message to be replied not found. Also, for some reason this reply is only visible to me. aiogram 2.25.1. MAIN ECHO FUNCTION:
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def echo(msg: types.Message):
    global is_bot_closed
    current_time = time.time()
    
    if is_bot_closed and msg.from_user.id != ADMIN_ID:
        await msg.reply("Сейчас писать могут только админы.")
        return

    
    if msg.from_user.id in last_message_time:
        time_since_last_message = current_time - last_message_time[msg.from_user.id]
        time_remaining = MESSAGE_DELAY - time_since_last_message

        if time_remaining > 0:
            await msg.reply(f"Подождите еще {round(time_remaining, 1)} секунд.")
            return

    
    last_message_time[msg.from_user.id] = current_time

    
    if db.is_user_banned(msg.from_user.id):
        await msg.reply('Вы забанены и не можете использовать этого бота. Обратитесь к @cry4he1p')
        return

    if not db.sas(msg.from_user.id):
        await msg.reply('Сначала введите команду /start, чтобы начать взаимодействие с ботом.')
        return

    
    if msg.reply_to_message is not None:
        original_message_id = msg.reply_to_message.message_id
    else:
        original_message_id = None

    user_id = msg.from_user.id
    is_anon = db.get_anon_mode(user_id)
    show_link = db.get_show_link(user_id)

    x = db.get_ids()
    users = len(x)
    keyboard = create_keyboard(user_id, msg.from_user.first_name, anon=is_anon, show_link=show_link)
    reply_message = await msg.reply(f'Отправляю ваше сообщение {users} пользователям. (а может и нет..)')

    for i in x:
        try:
            zc = db.chek(i[0])
            if zc[0][0] == 1:
                try:
                    if msg.content_type == types.ContentType.TEXT:
                        await bot.send_message(chat_id=i[0], text=msg.text, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.PHOTO:
                        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=i[0], photo=msg.photo[-1].file_id, caption=msg.caption, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.AUDIO:
                        await bot.send_audio(chat_id=i[0], audio=msg.audio.file_id, caption=msg.caption, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.DOCUMENT:
                        await bot.send_document(chat_id=i[0], document=msg.document.file_id, caption=msg.caption, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.VIDEO:
                        await bot.send_video(chat_id=i[0], video=msg.video.file_id, caption=msg.caption, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.ANIMATION:
                        await bot.send_animation(chat_id=i[0], animation=msg.animation.file_id, caption=msg.caption, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.VOICE:
                        await bot.send_voice(chat_id=i[0], voice=msg.voice.file_id, caption=msg.caption, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.VIDEO_NOTE:
                        await bot.send_video_note(chat_id=i[0], video_note=msg.video_note.file_id, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                    elif msg.content_type == types.ContentType.STICKER:
                        await bot.send_sticker(chat_id=i[0], sticker=msg.sticker.file_id, reply_markup=keyboard, reply_to_message_id=original_message_id)
                except (BotBlocked, ChatNotFound, UserDeactivated):
                    logging.error(f"User {i[0]} has blocked the bot, the chat does not exist, or the user is deactivated. Skipping.")
                except aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToReplyNotFound:
                    logging.error(f'Message to reply to {original_message_id} not found for user {i[0]}. Skipping reply.')
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f'Error sending message to {i[0]}: {e}')

                if not db.sas(msg.from_user.id):
                    await db.add(msg.from_user.id, msg.from_user.username)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Error processing user {i[0]}: {e}')
          
    await asyncio.sleep(REPLY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT)
    try:
        await bot.delete_message(chat_id=msg.chat.id, message_id=reply_message.message_id)
    except aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound:
        logging.error(f'Message to delete {reply_message.message_id} not found.')

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
